# Pad strings by spaces to certain length

Tags: mysql, sql, string-formatting

Consider the following two strings,

```
source
-------
'ADAM'  -- 4 chars length
'BOB'   -- 3 chars length
```

I want to concatenate spaces after the strings where *the number of spaces + length of string(n)* should *not* exceed a specific number.

So the output should look something like the below where `n = 8` in this case.

```
result
-----------
'ADAM    '  -- 8 chars length 
'BOB     '  -- 8 chars length
```

How can I do this in mysql dynamically?

I could check the length of the field and use case statements for each scenario but thats not ideal. I am using **mysql** 8.0.17.

Comment: They just are. I have data like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the function [`rpad()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad):

```
select rpad(name, 8, ' ')
```